# MySQL db version control: Makes sense to express db as file/folder hierarchy?

Tags: mysql, controls, version

I am looking for a better way to put MySQL database under version control. I currently put raw dumps under version control. This is bad because I end up diffing one huge file, and it's hard to immediately know which tables changed (e.g. which table does this changed line belong to? How many tables are changed in this commit?). Merging also *feels* a bit more risky when working with a single big file (again, the same problem of, "which table does this changed line belong to"?)

After reading about solutions on stackoverflow, I think Liquibase seems to be a good tool for database versioning. However, I am exploring another *seemingly* simpler method:

It seems to me that MySQL databases actually map to a tree data structure very well (am I mistaken?). Therefore, it is possible to just dump a MySQL database into a file system, i.e. a file/folder structure, like so:

```
Tables (dir)
    Table1 (dir)
        data.xml (file denoting Table1's data)
    Table2 (dir)
        data.xml (file denoting Table1's data)
```

etc.

Alternatively, we could represent the database in a file system like so:

```
Tables (dir)
    Table1 (dir)
        Column1.xml (Column1 data from Table1)
        Column2.xml (Column2 data from Table1)
```

etc.

These file/folders can then be put under version control, and very easily tracked for change history.

I know that there are many discussions around database versioning, and my impression so far from googling is that, this is a tricky subject. So, for me to think that the solution is so straightforward, *something* must be amiss!

Will this work? What are the flaws in this approach to putting MySQL database under version control?

Comment: What needs to you have - do you simply need to have each database snapshot available for re-import, or do you really need to manually track down changes using `diff`? Because if it's the former, you could simply store a clear-text dump for each revision.

Comment: I need to track content changes (the schema is relatively stable). More specifically, I need to merge content changes (schema unchanged) between development and live databases. So I thought expressing the db as a file system allows me to tap on the merge functionality of "conventional/modern" version control systems.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) already can dump data as XML. Note however, that due to a lot of redundancy in metadata, XML is not really efficient way to store raw data. Just plain SQL dumps or CSV files would be better.

Comment: Putting raw dumps under version control is what I am doing now. The problem with that is that I end up diffing one big blob of a file. By expressing the schema as a folder structure, I can zoom into changes more quickly, and immediately know which table (folder) the change is in. Diffing would also be quicker.

Comment: That's true. It's just a question of querying `information_schema` for list of tables in your databse and then calling `mysqldump` with appropriate arguments to dump a single table at a time.

Comment: @cranberry Take a step back. What is changing the database? Put that under version control instead.